# Long Boot Time, sanitized_helper at fault (dmesg)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dmesg

I have a desktop that has a 4.5 Ghz 6-core processor, 16GB or RAM, and an SSD. It is dual-boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. It boot Windows 10 in ~8 to 10 seconds, while it takes Ubuntu over 3.5 minutes to boot. When I run`dmesg`, I can see that a process called`sanitized_helper`takes almost 100 seconds to load (?). Then, Bluetooth: RFCOMM v.1.11 takes 110 seconds to load.

First of all, what is "sanitized_helper"? And concerning Bluetooth, Sure, I could disable Bluetooth on boot, but why does it take that long anyway?

Here is the complete`dmesg`output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15344458/

EDIT: As Jeremy31 suggested, I booted into Windows 10 and shutdown with`shutdown -h` and re-ran `dmesg`. Ubuntu now boots in around a minute and a half, which is still a long time, but its progress! Here is the complete `dmesg` output after shutting down in that way: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15344524/

Here are the contents of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0b569c46-6cc7-4453-a9ac-7b1828cb202b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=AAA6-1955  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=e46d8b08-ea89-4045-8737-e977888b12f5 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

And here's the output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="2480A41480A3EA8E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8b6f744e-e767-4348-a14e-0a23726cea33"
/dev/sda2: UUID="AAA6-1955" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="676ee6a5-5b9c-4566-b13e-026ccc5deb1c"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="b36a3fce-16dd-4b30-9756-16266ffb1c8b"
/dev/sda4: UUID="0848B0D943211234" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="01a32f3e-31d7-4429-b80e-b538d7b53cd4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="0b569c46-6cc7-4453-a9ac-7b1828cb202b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a0d08d18-d9db-4e68-afe8-e5bac0bd8755"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="8f2b6a8e-c0bd-447a-9f41-390249d4866b"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="2TB Seagate" UUID="2698A69B98A668CF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="3399edd9-593b-41e6-8bf2-e82f0166da70"
```

Comment: Check this answer: [Ubuntu 15.04 is loading very slow](http://askubuntu.com/questions/616523). Some mounting issue, rather than AppArmor problem. Do you have encrypted volumes?

Comment: If your UUID in `/etc/fstab` is OK, try replacing UUIDs in this file with proper partition names `/dev/sdXY`, as mentioned here: [15.10 boots very slow](http://software.techforums.space/software/ubuntu-1510-boot-very-slow-cgroup-new-mount-options-do-not-match-the-existing-superblock-will-be-ignored-solution-6dd43bf6.html)

Comment: You could post the entire dmesg output at paste.ubuntu.com and then post the link.  It almost looks like Win10 is using its hybrid shutdown instead of a full shutdown

Comment: +whtyger No, none of the volumes are encrypted.

Comment: What about the other links? Have you checked them? Replacing UUIDs with the device names can resolve your issue. Be careful, make a backup of `/etc/fstab` beforehand. You can find device name equivalents for your UUIDs using the command `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Boot into windows, open command prompt and enter `shutdown /s` then boot into Ubuntu and see if errors in dmesg change

Comment: @Jeremy31 Sorry about the long delay, everyone. I shutdown Windows with `shutdown /s`, and then booted back into Ubuntu. Here is the complete `dmesg` output after shutting down Windows properly (a link to the complete output prior to doing this is now in the original post): http://paste.ubuntu.com/15344524/

Comment: I think you may have installed Ubuntu after a hybrid shutdown in Windows and that messed things up, I don't know how to fix but this is the problem from dmesg `[   16.408915] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   98.233882] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored`

Comment: I just tried whtyger's answer, and it has screwed stuff up even more. It won't boot fully. I can press alt+f2, and login, to try to copy my /etc/fstab back. It won't let me, saying that it is a read-only filesystem. Any ideas? And thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Have you got a LiveCD? Boot from it and restore your `/etc/fstab` from backup. If you haven't got DVD drive, you can make Live USB. There's also restore root shell, but you'd better try the mentioned method first. When your system is bootable again, post your `/etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid` outputs.

Comment: @whtyger I have successfully restored my `fstab` file. Here is the content of my `fstab` file and the output of `sudo blkid`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15348141/

Comment: Good. Store `fstab` backup - you may need it. Strange that `blkid` output contains no swap partition info - I cannot compare UUIDs. So you replaced `UUID=0b569c46...7b1828cb202b` with `/dev/sda5`, `UUID=AAA6-1955` with `/dev/sda2` and `UUID=e46d8b08...e977888b12f5` with `/dev/sda6`, right? Typos are impossible? Then try replacing UUIDs with device names one by one, rebooting after each change. If it won't help, restore your `/etc/fstab` and try commenting out the string starting from `UUID=AAA6-1955` - will this operation affect booting timeout?

Comment: @whtyger I don't have a swap partition because this computer has 16GB RAM, which is way more than I will ever need.

Comment: @willem.hill But your `/etc/fstab` file definitely shows swap among the partitions that should be mounted on boot. If you are sure that you have no swap partition, remove its respective line from `/etc/fstab` (or comment out for safety). This should fix your issue. **P.S.** Even huge amount of RAM doesn't mean that you should refuse from using swap entirely. Here's the [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) which explains that.

Comment: Lines 1093 to 1097 stand out to me.  What version of the Nvidia driver are you using?

Comment: I would checkout what apparmor is doing. You might have a bogus profile setting. since this post is the first in the list on google for sanitized_helper, sanitizesd helper might not be the name of the thing generation the issue.

Comment: @whtyger Do I replace the entire `UUID=0b569...` with `/dev/sda5`, or just the UUID, for example `UUID = /dev/sda5`?

Comment: And sorry for the long delay everyone, this is my work computer, so I couldn't try to fix this during the weekend...

Comment: Start from commenting the string beginning from `UUID=e46d8b08...`. Paste `#`sign in front of it: `#UUID=e46d8b08...`, save and reboot. If that won't help (but I think that should), restore your backup of `/etc/fstab` and try replacing `UUID=e46d8b08-ea89-4045-8737-e977888b12f5` (entirely) with `/dev/sda6`.

Comment: @whtyger Hmm... both result in a system that just boots to a terminal.

Comment: @willem.hill That's strange indeed. Using device name, UUID, PARTLABEL and PARTUUID in `/etc/fstab` is [interchangeable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID). Another method of fixing incorrect swap UUID is to remove swap partition and recreate it again with gparted. In that case its UUID will be renewed and this new UUID should be placed into `/etc/fstab`. But I'm not sure that this will work, as you told that there's no swap left in your system.